# Do not create widget

Tags: android, android-widget

Hello this is simple question

i create widget and test this is my simple code :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);

        Log.d(" widget ids : " + Arrays.toString(ids) );


        setResultCode(0);
}
```

But i have got red square on home screen .. ?

My widget provider configuration :

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:minHeight="80dp"

    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"

    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
But i have got red square on home screen .. ?
```

This could be the preview image you have set in widget provider xml.

**When the widget is added in home screen, the onUpdate() method will be called, where you can set the  remote layout for the widget like this.**

```
public class CustomAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider{
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
 }
```

}

You can also set a pending intent to an activity/service to be invoked when the whole widget or an child item in the widget is clicked

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,0);
  remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView1,pendingIntent);
```

*So, here in the widget layout there is a textview , and when the user click on the textview the MainActivity will be launched.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an layout file to your appwidget-provider:

```
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_view"
```

In this layout file you have to put Buttons, Images, TextViews etc. whatever you need.